Instagram automation selenium webdriver
I'm getting automation detected pop-ups and I'm wondering what measures can I take so this won't become an issue? Almost after every command I have an random sleep timer and also did some settings for the driver which I will paste below, there is for sure some more settings or maybe I've done them wrong.
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    prefs = {
        "credentials_enable_service": False,
        "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")


as I know Selenium uses some variables in JavaScript and some portals use it to detect Selenium. There is special driver undetected-chromedriver which uses random names for variables.

@furas Thank, will give it a try

You could also see nodriver (the same author) but he tries to make code simpler - it hides selenium an drivers. But if you have code for selenium then with undetected-chromedriver you need only few changes.

javascript - Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver? - Stack Overflow
